# cannot use d3 to create a word cloud

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner of d3. I tried to create a word cloud using d3, but it does not work. There is no output on browser. Would someone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you very much.
Following is my code:

test3.html:
    
    
    
    
    D3 Word Clouds
    
    
    
    
    
    cloud/master/d3.layout.cloud.js">

```
<script>
  var filename = 'example.csv';

  d3.csv(filename, function(data){
    data = data.splice(0, 6);

    var width = 1200,
    height = 600,
    fill = d3.scale.category20(),
    maxcount = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.count; } ),
    wordcount = data.map(function(d) { return {text: d.word, size: 
    d.count / maxcount * 10}; });

    d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
    .words(wordcount)
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw)
    .start();

    function draw(words) {
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height
      })
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [ width >> 1, height >> 1 ] + 
      ")")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(words)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .style({
        "font-size": function(d) { return d.size + "px"; },
        "font-family": "Impact",
        "fill": function(d, i) { return fill(i); }
      })
      .attr({
        "text-anchor": "middle",
        "transform": function(d) { return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + 
      ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")"; }
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

example.csv:

```
aaa,10
bbb,2
ccc,15
ddd,20
eee,10
f,12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me with one change.  d3 is expecting your CSV file to have headers of `word` and `count`:

```
word,count
aaa,10
bbb,2
ccc,15
ddd,20
eee,10
f,12
```

[Here's your code working](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKGzZGDUocrJ2lFvUXrh?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. Exactly I need to add headers for csv file. But  still failed. There is nothing output in the browser.

Comment: I also tried other simpler examples to check whether it read out csv data correctly or not. Then I found all the examples are failed to read out csv data. Would you help me to find out what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out, there is no other problems in the source code. But Chrome has strict permissions for reading files out of the local file system. So I failed to open it with "file:///".
There is a good material http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/ to learn d3 before jumping into tutorial.